# How can I connect to a USB printer shared by an Apple AirPort?

Tags: printing

I've just moved from Mac OS X to Ubuntu, now I'm running Ubuntu natively on a dedicated partition on a Mac, and I've an Apple AirPort wifi router, sharing a USB printer with my family.

The problem is that I've not yet found any way to print from Ubuntu. Can someone help?